# Проблема с рекурсией. Вычислить y(n)=1/(1+(1/(2+(1/(3+(1/......+1/((n-1)+1/n)

Tags: c++, математика, рекурсия, непрерывные-дроби

Вычислить y(n)=1/(1+(1/(2+(1/(3+(1/......+1/((n-1)+1/n).

надо получить условно 1/(1+1/(2+1/(3+1/(4+1/5))))

а выходит рекурсия  1/(5+1/(4+1/(3+1/(2+1))))

не знаю как сделать правильно

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double calRec(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else return 1 / (n + calRec(n - 1));
}

double cal(int n) {
    double result = 1 / n;

    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
        result = 1 / (i + result);
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    int n = 5;

    // Вычисление значения с использованием рекурсии
    double recRes = calRec(n);

    // Вычисление значения без использования рекурсии
    double Res = cal(n);

    cout << "y(" << n << ") (рекурсивно) = " << recRes << endl;
    cout << "y(" << n << ") (итеративно) = " << Res << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В рекурсии "выверните" счётчик. Пусть растёт а не убывает.

Comment: надо только понять как вывернуть. В методе нашего препода только факториал и показывают, а там как раз убывание.

Comment: придётся ещё один параметр в рекурсивную функцию передавать

Comment: Факториал рекурсивно тоже можно двумя способами сосчитать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
double calRec(int n, int m = 1)
{
    if (m >= n)
        return 1./m;
    else return 1 / (m + calRec(n, m+1));
}
```

Здесь `m` — текущее значение, а `n` — максимальное.

Смысл в том, что идем не сверху вниз, а снизу вверх.

Answer (score 1):

Линейная/хвостовая рекурсия:

```
double calRec(int n, double s) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return s;
    }
    return calRec(n - 1, 1 / (n + s));
}
```

Вызывать с нулём:

```
double recRes = calRec(n, 0);
```

Comment: Можно вызывать и без нуля, если написать `double calRec(int n, double s = 0)` :)